# Tableau filter a dimension without affecting table grand total

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have faculty performance evaluation data at my school, organized by department. Some faculty are not affiliated with any dept, i.e., their dept field is missing (null value). I created a dept filter and wanted to achieve two similar goals:

1. filter out faculty who are null dept in view but include them in calculating school average
2. select any dept from the dept filter without changing the school average.

In the end, I want to show all depts in view, with dept filter on the side, and readers decide which depts to include in the view, but regardless of how many depts are chosen the grand total/school average stays the same.

Here is the sample [workbook](https://public.tableau.com/profile/ji.zhou#!/vizhome/QuestionFilterDimensionWithoutAffectingTableGrandTotal/Sheet1). This is a common problem for a majority of my workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

For step 1), right click on the Null Dept in your first column, and choose **Hide**. The data is still included, just not displayed, so it won't change the Grand Total.

For step 2), it will take more than one mouse click, but can be done by combining a few features. If you only want to show one Department at a time, and your Department's don't change, then

1. Create a parameter to select the department to show
2. Create a calculated field or a set to denote which department to show
3. Place that field on the row shelf and use it to hide other departments

LOD calculations are also very useful for these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Your solution helps with some dashboards, where showing one department is preferable.
 
For a lot of my dashboards, faculty/dept chairs would like to see all depts in the window, and then decide whether to select/filter to see only certain depts. Any suggestions?

Comment: The end result would be: show all depts in view, with dept filter on the side, and readers decide which depts to include in the view, but regard of how many depts are chosen the grand total/school average stays the same.

Comment: One technique that will be valuable in that second case is to use level of detail (LOD) calculations. In particular, FIXED LOD calcs. So I recommend learning how FIXED LOD calcs work, then learning how they interact with filters. Then see if you can use them to craft a solution to your specific case.

Comment: I don't see FIXED LOD would work here, not that I know. If FIXED to all data, the calculated field would show the school average for each person. If FIXED to dept and name level, the grand total would still change if certain depts are un-selected.

Comment: You would use a LOD calc for the grand total. Fixed LOD calcs are computed prior to applying dimension filters.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from the Tableau forum helped figure out this question. Create a calculated field for dept filter, using the code: lookup(min([Dept]),0). Use this filter to let users select dept. The grand total stays the same.

https://community.tableau.com/message/596484#596484